# How to integrate the existing system in WSO2 DAS

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi, wso2-das

We have a large number of algorithms written in C++ and Java.
Now we want to introduce the WSO2 DAS platform.
Where and how can we integrate these algorithms with DAS?

I should explain more info: these algorithms are running realtime analytics, but we found that DAS uses `siddhi` for realtime analytics, and it doesn't provide any interface or API that we can use for these algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2DAS consist with event receivers where you  Java and C++ applications can push data by using several protocols such as thrift, http, soap, mqtt, jms, kafka and etc [1]

Siddhi can be used as a Java Library within your applications or else you can create a event flow with streams and receivers in WSO2 DAS and add Siddhi queries in an Execution Plan. For more details please refer Siddhi documentation [2]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Configuring+Event+Receivers

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP400/SiddhiQL+Guide+3.0

Comment: The algorithm system contains more than 100 algorithm , most of the algorithm is written by c++ that generated by scilab engine. Each algorithm  pull datas from another system, and after processing , it send result to storing system(which just write to DB). Our customer would generate the algorithm by themselve, and they send us a package file(like zip), or they deploy them to the algorithm system. But the deployment of algorithm system is terrible, and lack of monitoring , logging, stable. So we want to introduce WSO2 product to solve our problem.

Comment: We can't change the alogrithm code, and we can't use siddhi to rewrite exsiting algorithm, but we can apply input and output interface. We want WSO2 can help us managing these algorithm that we can manage their liftcycle, monitoring their processing, trace the input/output datas, even fire them by the event sent from DAS etc.Thanks for your any help.

Comment: In that case you need to use DAS to get events from outside and then do further processing, monitoring, logging and etc. After that DAS can publish data to your algorithm application using a protocol like thrift. The results of the algrothim can be pushed back to DAS by using DAS wso2 event receiver. Here you need to use existing algorithms and write interface application to receiver and publish events using a protocol like thrift.